# A Simple HTML Checkbox with PHP Problem

Tags: php, html

I have a field in my update form called approve which is using the html checkbox element. now i am querying the approve value from the database which will hold the binary value (0 or 1), i want the checkbox to perofrm the following actions in condition.

a) While Querying from database.

1)if the value of active is 1 then it should be checked by default and also it should hold the value 1 to process  it to update
2)the same applies for 0, if the value is zero then it is unchecked and will hold the value 0 to process

P.S: I want to use this for updating the form not inserting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

**PHP embedded in HTML way**:

```
 <input name="chk" type="checkbox" value="<?=$value?>" <?php if($value==1) echo 'checked="checked"';?> />
```

**Pure PHP way**:

```
 <?php
 echo '<input name="chk" type="checkbox" value="'.$value.'"';
 if($value == 1)
      echo ' checked="checked" ';
 echo '/>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a 1-line shorter version ;)

```
<?php echo "<input name=\"chk\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$value\"".( ($value == 1) ? " checked=\"checked\"" : "" )." />"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['approved']; ?>" <?php if($row['approved'] == 1): echo 'checked="checked"'; endif; />
```

Comment: i would go with the solution provided by @shamittomar that sounds feasible, thank you for your take..